# find a path to a given node in binary tree - Python

Tags: python, tree, binary, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm stuck finding the path of the given node so I can find the right side but not the left side.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

    def path(self, k):
      if not self.val:
         return []
      if self.val == k:
        return [self.val]
      res = self.left.path(k)
      if res:
         return [self.val] + res
      res = self.right.path(k)
      if res:
         return [self.val] + res
      return []
```

For example, when I search for `5` in `X="+ * + 5 7 4 1 6"`, the output is like `['+', '*', '+', '5']` but when I try to search for any number on the lift subtree, it gives me this error:

```
[Previous line repeated 1 more time]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'path'
```

Comment: You should verify `self.right` is a `Node` and not `None` before attempting to call `.path()` on it. The same goes for `self.left`.

Comment: This is the type of errors you can easily resolve yourself if you use a debugger, and step through your code and inspect values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before accessing a method like `path` you should ensure that the object really is a `Node` instance, and not `None`.

Not the problem, but `not self.val` will also be a true expression when that `val` is 0, which seems like a valid key for a node... I suppose this test is there to detect a node with a `None` value. Usually such code is used when a tree is always created with at least one node instance, even when it is empty. This is not good practice. An empty tree should not have nodes at all, not even one with a `None` value.

So correct to:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, key):
        self.left = None
        self.right = None
        self.val = key

    def path(self, k):
        if self.val == k:
            return [self.val]
        if self.left:
            res = self.left.path(k)
            if res:
                return [self.val] + res
        if self.right:
            res = self.right.path(k)
            if res:
                return [self.val] + res
        return []
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! , but I have a question why we need to check if that the object really is a Node instance and not none ?

Comment: Well, `None.path` is not something that makes sense to Python. So if `self.left` is `None` (which means the current node has no left child), we should not attempt to access `self.left.path` -- as this means we ask Python to give us `None.path`

Comment: Thank you so much I got  a clear image now , but I still didn't get what the purpose of__ if res:  return [self.val] + res___ what do you mean with if res ? 
Thanks !

Comment: Why do you ask? It is your code -- I didn't change that `if res`. Is it not your code? It is a bit odd when I have to explain your code to you?

Comment: `res` is a list. The `if res` condition will be a false one when it is an **empty** list and it will be a true one when `res` is non-empty. The latter means that the value `k` was successfully found deeper in recursion, and `res` represents the deeper path to it.